# How to determine $x$?

Tags: functions

> If $f\left(\dfrac{x-1}{x+1}\right)=x^2+x-1$. What is $x=?$
>
> A) $0\quad$ B) $1\quad$ C)$-1\quad$ D)$2\quad$ E)$-2$

I believe, the problem is missing something, because for every $x$ I plug in, there exists a value of the function.

Comment: This depends obviously of which function $f$ you are considering.

Comment: This is the only information I've been given in the exam. Can you please explain what do you mean by which function $f$?

Comment: $x$ can be $0$ is $f$ is constant equal to $-1$ for example. It can be $x=1$ if $f$ is constant equal to $1$. It can be $x=2$ if $f$ is constant equal to $5$. It can be $x=-2$ if $f$ is constant equal to $1$. The only answer $x$ *cannot* be is $-1$, because in that case, the quotient is not defined.

Comment: It is dubious that the question was reproduced verbatim/in extenso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments, there is clearly something amiss in the problem as it is stated here. To underscore that fact, notice that the function $f$ is implicitly defined by the equation

$$ f\left(\dfrac{x-1}{x+1}\right)=x^2+x-1 $$

If we let $t=\dfrac{x-1}{x+1}$ we find that

$$ f(t)=-\frac{t^2-4t+1}{(t-1)^2} $$

which is define for all $t\ne1$. But there is no value of $x$ for which $t=1$.

So there is nothing about the definition of the function which implies any specific value of $x$.